# Jquery animation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to animate a series of words I'm trying to just get one word to roll down into view then stay for a half second and then disappear out of view by rolling down (like a lotto machine).

The overflow for the div is hidden so the words are out of view at top: -20 and at top: 20 but in view around top 5 or top 0. But each time the setInterval runs it displays the .rw-word at a different location, also the timing seems to be off....

Here's what I have so far:
html :

```
<div id="login-modal" class="modal">
  <section class='rw-wrapper'>
    <h3 class='rw-sentance'>LOG IN TO START
            <div class="rw-words">
                <span class="rw-word">COLLECTING</span>
            </div>
        </h3>
  </section>
```

css:

```
.rw-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.rw-sentance {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 21px;
}

.rw-sentance span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.rw-words {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  position: relative;
}

.rw-words span {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 40%;
  color: #F58835;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#account-login', function (){
      wordScroll();
    });

    setInterval(wordScroll, 2000);
    function wordScroll() {
      $('.rw-word').delay(200).animate({ top: '0'}, 100,function(){
        $('.rw-word').delay(4000).animate({ top: '25'}, 100,function(){
          $('.rw-word').css('top','-20px');
        });
      });
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8odyjh2/1/)

Comment: any fiddle? please could help to help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u8odyjh2/1/

Comment: no scroll in your fiddle?

Comment: no, scroll is just the name of the function, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place `setInterval(wordScroll, 2000);` withing the click event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#account-login', function (){
  //wordScroll();
    setInterval(wordScroll, 2000);
});

function wordScroll() {
  $('.rw-word').delay(200).animate({ top: '0'}, 100,function(){
    $('.rw-word').delay(4000).animate({ top: '25'}, 100,function(){
      $('.rw-word').css('top','-20px');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: yes I did that but it's still not animating the rw-word back to top: 0